# Jackson use JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL except for one class

Tags: jackson

I normally use objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL) because I never want the null values of my classes serialized. Except now I have a specific field should be written out, even if it is null. Is there a quick annotation I can put on this one field that overrides the Inclusion.NON_NULL property for that one field? What's a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

With Jackson 1.x you can use `@JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.ALWAYS)` and with Jackson 2.x you can use `@JsonInclude(Include.ALWAYS)`. These annotations will override the default config from your `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: Can you please mention Jackson 2.x jar name and @JsonSerialize package.

Comment: The Jackson 1.x stuff is under the org.codehaus.jackson package and 2.x is under com.fasterxml.jackson

Answer (score 19):

@user1433372, JsonInclude is an annotation only for Jackson 2.x.

in Jackson 1.9

```
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)
```

is the same in Jackson 2.x as

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
```

Comment: JSON 2.97 = com.fasterxml.jackson 2.9.7?

Answer (score 3):

With Jackson 1.9 is used `@JsonSerialize(include= JsonSerialize.Inclusion.ALWAYS)`

`@JsonSerialize(include=Include.ALWAYS)` did not compile.

Comment: @JsonSerialize(include= JsonSerialize.Inclusion.ALWAYS) not works for me!